# Modifying entries of a pandas dataframe within a loop

Tags: python, loops, pandas, dataframe

I want to add the probabilities of each record within a dataframe for that I used a for loop

```
def map_score(dataframe,customers,prob):
  dataframe['Propensity'] = 0
  for i in range(len(dataframe)):
      for j in range(len(customers)):
          if dataframe['Client'].iloc[i] == customers[j]:
              dataframe["Propensity"].iloc[i] = prob[j]
```

I am able to map the Probabilities associated with each client correctly, but Python throws a warning message

> A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
>   Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
>
> See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
>     from ipykernel import kernelapp as app

When I use .loc function, the result is erroneous and I am getting null values.
Kindly suggest a good method to update and add entries conditionally

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to make assignment on a copy.
`dataframe["Propensity"]` is one column, yet a "copy" of `dataframe`.

However, you are tracking index position with `i`.  So how do you get to use `.loc` when you have a column name `"Propensity"` and an index location `i`.

Assign some variable, say `idx`, equal to `dataframe.index` at that location

```
idx = dataframe.index[i]
```

Then you can use `.loc` with the assignment and without issues

```
dataframe.loc[idx, "Propensity"] = prob[j]
```

---

```
def map_score(dataframe,customers,prob):
  dataframe['Propensity'] = 0
  for i in range(len(dataframe)):
      idx = dataframe.index[i]
      for j in range(len(customers)):
          if dataframe['Client'].iloc[i] == customers[j]:
              dataframe.loc[idx, "Propensity"] = prob[j]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I get it now. Is there a way to avoid loop within loop in this case. I basically want to match dataframe.clients with the array which has the Clients, and the probability array has the same order as the client array. So basically I want to add the probability to the index  where the clients match

Comment: This question is about the warning.  I'd ask a another question about the loop.  And when you do, please add some sample data so we can see what you see.

Comment: Thanks piRSquared, I appreciate your valuable feedback:)